# How to use the cli utility of a python package within an argparse-packaged executable in windows

Tags: python, subprocess, command-line-interface, filenotfoundexception

I have a python CLI package that I am packaging into an executable with `pyinstaller`. My package uses `subprocess` to use a CLI function from one of the dependencies:

```
subprocess.run([
    "openai", "tools", "fine_tunes.prepare_data",
    "-f", dataset_absolute_path,
    "-q"
])
```

When run as a pip package, this works fine. When run as a packaged executable, it works on linux but not on windows, with this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

At first I thought it was an issue with the file path I was using, but even when just running

```
subprocess.run([
    "openai", "-v"
])
```

It still returns `FileNotFoundError`.

Comment: It may be that the openai binary directory isn't in PATH. Windows doesn't have a standard place to put binaries making it hard to run them programatically. Can `where openai` find the program and is it in PATH?

Comment: It can't. So is the issue that it is trying to use `openai` from my window's PATH, rather than  the one included in the package? How would I point it to the packaged `openai`?